# How to reference outer query from subquery in AzureDataExplorer/Kusto for filter + extend?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have two tables that both contain health events for some entity. Table1 contains frequent events taken minutes apart. Table 2 could be anywhere from minutes to months apart. I want to correlate the most recent health event from table 2 to table 1 for some entity.

```
let Table1 = datatable (Table1Timestamp : datetime, Table1NameOfDataElement : string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:05:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:15:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:12:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:09:00), 'bar',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:15:00), 'bar',
];
let Table2 = datatable (Table2Timestamp : datetime, Table2NameOfDataElement : string, Other: int)
[
    // Data is ragged, days before first entry but is current state of 'foo'
    datetime(2021-05-09 19:05:00), 'foo', 1,
    datetime(2021-05-09 19:05:00), 'bar', 2,
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:09:00), 'bar', 3,
];
Table1
| where Table1Timestamp between (datetime(2021-05-11 19:00:00) .. datetime(2021-05-11 20:00:00))
// determine state of entity in table 1 every 10 minutes
| summarize arg_max(Table1Timestamp, *) by Table1NameOfDataElement, TimeInterval = bin(Table1Timestamp, 10minutes)
// Find the row in table2 that is closest in time proximity to the row from table 1
// This naive approach will not compile
| extend MostRecentColumnInOtherTable = toscalar(Table2 
                               | where Table2Timestamp < **Table1Timestamp** 
                               | where Table2NameOfDataElement == **Table1NameOfDataElement** 
                               | top 1 by Table2Timestamp | project Other)
```

I can't do this since kql does not allow me to reference columns from the outer query in an inner query. I could join on the entity name but that only solves half the problem, I need to lookup the last entry before the event in table 1.

A naive approach would be to join on `bin(Table2Timestamp, 10minutes) == bin(table1Timestamp, 10minutes)` but the data in table 2 can be many months away from the relevant row in table 1, table 2 only logs changes in state when they happen.

Table 1 has a narrow window and typically contains thousands of rows. Table2 can go back many months and contains hundreds of thousands of rows.

How can I do a fast lookup for last change in table2 that occurred before a row in table1?

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works for me. Just do the join on the entity name and then aggregate with arg_min to find the rows where the timestamp difference is minimized

```
let Table1 = datatable (Table1Timestamp : datetime, Table1NameOfDataElement : string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:05:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:15:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:12:00), 'foo',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:09:00), 'bar',
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:15:00), 'bar',
];
let Table2 = datatable (Table2Timestamp : datetime, Table2NameOfDataElement : string, Other: int)
[
    // Data is ragged, days before first entry but is current state of 'foo'
    datetime(2021-05-09 19:05:00), 'foo', 1,
    datetime(2021-05-09 19:05:00), 'bar', 2,
    datetime(2021-05-11 19:09:00), 'bar', 3,
];
Table1
| where Table1Timestamp between (datetime(2021-05-11 19:00:00) .. datetime(2021-05-11 20:00:00))
// determine state of entity in table 1 every 10 minutes
| summarize arg_max(Table1Timestamp, *) by Table1NameOfDataElement, TimeInterval = bin(Table1Timestamp, 10minutes)
// Find the row in table2 that is closest in time proximity to the row from table 1
// This naive approach will not compile
| Lookup Table2 on $left.Table1NameOfDataElement == $right.Table1NameOfDataElement 
| where Table1Timestamp < Table2Timestamp
| summarize arg_min(TimeDiffFromTimestamp = datetime_diff('second', Table1Timestamp, Table2Timestamp), *) by bin(Table1TimeStamp), Table1NameOfDataElement
```